# Scrapy spider finding one "Next" button but not the other

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am writing a spider to scrape a popular reviews website :-) This is my first attempt at writing a Scrapy spider.

The top level is a list of restaurants (I call this "top level"), which appear 30 at a time. My spider accesses each link and then "clicks next" to get the next 30, and so on. This part is working as my output does contain thousands of restaurants, not just the first 30.

I then want it to "click" on the link to each restaurant page ("restaurant level"), but this contains only truncated versions of the reviews, so I want it to then "click" down a further level (to "review level") and scrape the reviews from there, which appear 5 at a time with another "next" button. This is the only "level" from which I am extracting anything - the other levels just have links to access to get to the reviews and other info I want.

Most of this is working as I am getting all the information I want, but only for the first 5 reviews per restaurant. It is not "finding" the "next" button on the bottom "review level".

I have tried changing the order of commands within the parse method, but other than that I am coming up short of ideas! My xpaths are fine so it must be something to do with structure of the spider.

My spider looks thus:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request

class TripSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'tripadvisor'
    allowed_domains = ['tripadvisor.co.uk']
    start_urls = ['https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g187069-Manchester_Greater_Manchester_England.html']
    custom_settings = {
       'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
       # 'DEPTH_LIMIT': 3,
       'AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY': 0.5,
       'USER_AGENT': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36",
       # 'DEPTH_PRIORITY': 1,
       # 'SCHEDULER_DISK_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.PickleFifoDiskQueue',
       # 'SCHEDULER_MEMORY_QUEUE': 'scrapy.squeues.FifoMemoryQueue'
    }

    def scrape_review(self, response):
        restaurant_name_review = response.xpath('//div[@class="wrap"]//span[@class="taLnk "]//text()').extract()
        reviewer_name = response.xpath('//div[@class="username mo"]//text()').extract()
        review_rating = response.xpath('//div[@class="wrap"]/div[@class="rating reviewItemInline"]/span[starts-with(@class,"ui_bubble_rating")]').extract()
        review_title = response.xpath('//div[@class="wrap"]//span[@class="noQuotes"]//text()').extract()
        full_reviews = response.xpath('//div[@class="wrap"]/div[@class="prw_rup prw_reviews_text_summary_hsx"]/div[@class="entry"]/p').extract()
        review_date = response.xpath('//div[@class="prw_rup prw_reviews_stay_date_hsx"]/text()[not(parent::script)]').extract()
        restaurant_name = response.xpath('//div[@id="listing_main_sur"]//a[@class="HEADING"]//text()').extract() * len(full_reviews)
        restaurant_rating = response.xpath('//div[@class="userRating"]//@alt').extract() * len(full_reviews)
        restaurant_review_count = response.xpath('//div[@class="userRating"]//a//text()').extract() * len(full_reviews)

        for rvn, rvr, rvt, fr, rd, rn, rr, rvc in zip(reviewer_name, review_rating, review_title, full_reviews, review_date, restaurant_name, restaurant_rating, restaurant_review_count):
            reviews_dict = dict(zip(['reviewer_name', 'review_rating', 'review_title', 'full_reviews', 'review_date', 'restaurant_name', 'restaurant_rating', 'restaurant_review_count'], (rvn, rvr, rvt, fr, rd, rn, rr, rvc)))
            yield reviews_dict
            # print(reviews_dict)

    def parse(self, response):
        ### The parse method is what is actually being repeated / iterated
        for review in self.scrape_review(response):
            yield review
            # print(review)

        # access next page of resturants
        next_page_restaurants = response.xpath('//a[@class="nav next rndBtn ui_button primary taLnk"]/@href').extract_first()
        next_page_restaurants_url = response.urljoin(next_page_restaurants)
        yield Request(next_page_restaurants_url)
        print(next_page_restaurants_url)

        # access next page of reviews
        next_page_reviews = response.xpath('//a[@class="nav next taLnk "]/@href').extract_first()
        next_page_reviews_url = response.urljoin(next_page_reviews)
        yield Request(next_page_reviews_url)
        print(next_page_reviews_url)

        # access each restaurant page:
        url = response.xpath('//div[@id="EATERY_SEARCH_RESULTS"]/div/div/div/div/a[@target="_blank"]/@href').extract()
        for url_next in url:
            url_full = response.urljoin(url_next)
            yield Request(url_full)

        # "accesses the first review to get to the full reviews (not the truncated versions)"
        first_review = response.xpath('//a[@class="title "]/@href').extract_first() # extract first used as I only want to access one of the links on this page to get down to "review level"
        first_review_full = response.urljoin(first_review)
        yield Request(first_review_full)
        # print(first_review_full)
```

Comment: Can you post an actual link you're trying to scrape?

Comment: Sure, my start URL is https://www.tripadvisor.co.uk/Restaurants-g187069-Manchester_Greater_Manchester_England.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space at the end of the class value:
[image]

Try this:

```
next_page_reviews = response.xpath('//a[@class="nav next taLnk "]/@href').extract_first()
```

Here are some tips on matching classes partially: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#when-querying-by-class-consider-using-css

On a side note, you can define separate parse functions to make it clearer what each one is responsible for: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html?highlight=callback#more-examples-and-patterns

Comment: Thanks malberts. The page you are on is the restaurant page, which only contains partial reviews (if they are long). The spider should be going into one of the reviews on that page and scraping the reviews from reviews level, as they are complete there. The xpath I posted does match that next button. After I posted this yesterday I found callbacks and I thought that might help given the structure of the website, so I'm going to try and implement that today. Appreciate the pointers!

Comment: @DaveC Ah! I updated the answer. There seems to be an extra space in the class name.

Comment: hmm that's odd... there is definitely a space there in my code so that isn't the problem unfortunately. The problem seems to be that when I print both "next page" url's to the console during execution, they come up the same. Even though both "next page" xpaths are correct. When I test the xpath for next_page_reviews in the Scrapy shell, it comes up with the correct url for the next page, but the script seems to be returning the next restaurants page url instead of the reviews one. So maybe the bug is in the line `yield Request(next_page_reviews_url)`? Should this be something else?

Comment: @DaveC Can you maybe post your full spider? I want to play around with it to see what happens.

Comment: I seem to have made some progress and you might have been right about the missing space as it is now finding both next buttons. I am now getting reviews from several review-pages deep and across the first few pages of restaurants (it'll take a while to get to the later pages I guess as there are a lot of reviews!) The issue now is that it seems to be duplicating a lot of reviews in my output. I will amend the code in the main post to include the full spider so you can take a look if you don't mind. Thanks so much!